# Does runs-on in GitHub actions gets overridden if we use matrix?

Tags: github, github-actions

I'm new to GitHub Actions and was trying out the matrix build following an online course as follows:

```
name: Node.js CI

on:
  push:
    branches: [ master ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ master ]

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    strategy:
      fail-fast: false
      matrix:
        node-version: [10.x, 12.x]
        os: [ubuntu-latest, windows-2016]

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: npm install and build webpack
        run: |
          npm install
          npm run build
```

In that course, it is `runs-on: ubuntu-latest`, but still the matrix takes effect.

So does runs-on get overridden if the matrix is defined even if I don't explicitly say `runs-on: ${{ matrix.os }}`?

Thanks

Comment: Here, you defined the strategy with the matrix, but you're not using it anywhere, so it wouldn't be taken into consideration. You need to specify the `${{ matrix.os }}` somewhere first if you want to use it. So it won't override your runner here, you have to specify `runs-on: ${{ matrix.os }}`.

Comment: @GuiFalourd, yes that's what I was expecting, that it would only run on "ubuntu-latest" as I haven't yet used ${{ matrix.os }}. But still, I am seeing 4 jobs being run.

Comment: It's probably the same job running 4 times (twice for the different `node-version`; and twice for the different `os`) with the same step as nothing is using the matrix values there.

Comment: So if it's running for both the os mentioned, isn't it indirectly overriding runs-on??

Comment: I am not using matrix values in steps, because they simply don't need them.

Comment: Do you have the link to the workflow run to check what is informed there? It shouldn't override the runner because you didn't specify that the `os` field from the matrix should be used as the job `runs-on` field.

Comment: I just went through the logs that the action generates, and yep, you are ryt. It's simply running the job four times just because it detects that strategy, but because its still runs-in: ubuntu-latest, it's simply running the job 4 times on the same ubuntu-latest.

Comment: I think the course could use a serious update 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here, you defined the strategy with the matrix, but you're not using it anywhere, so those `node-version` and `os` values won't be taken into consideration.

Therefore, it won't override the runner because you didn't specify that the `os` field from the matrix should be used as the job `runs-on` field.

You need to specify the `${{ matrix.os }}` somewhere first if you want to use it. So it won't override your runner here, you have to specify `runs-on: ${{ matrix.os }}`

As you implemented your workflow, the same job will run 4 times as it will detect the `strategy` (twice for the different `node-version`; and twice for the different `os`) but with the same step and job configurations, as nothing is using the matrix values there.

Comment: Thanks, marking this as answer as per out discussion in the above comments :)